# Is it possible to get the return or result of authorize?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

I'm trying to get the authorize return, like Unauthorized or Authorized...
Is it possible do that using a HTTP GET Request?

```
    [Route("api/v1/endpoint")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Policy = SecurityInfo.SecurityPolicyTypes.Reader)]

    public class ControllerName: Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeQueries _employeeQueries;


        public EmployeeDocumentsController(IEmployeeQueries employeeQueries)
        {
            _employeeQueries = employeeQueries;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
        public async Task <IActionResult> GetCheck() 
        {
            if (User.HasClaim(c => c.Type != "hr.reader"))
                  return Unauthorized();

             return Ok();

        }
    }
}
```

c.type is returning a value like "nbf", I want to return the claims or the Unauthorized... how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You can get the result of any action if you implement a middleware. What I don't see is why you want that. Either you give access or not, it is not clear, for me, what it is you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Or you could use a standard `[Authorize]` attribute. If you get an HTTP 401 response, the user is not authorized.

Comment: As what others have said, use [Claims-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which is done outside of the controllers.

Comment: So, I'm using, but I need to know my authorize response to send to my front end... It's just a check method

Comment: Is this what you're trying ?`var userIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var claims = userIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type != "hr.reader");`

Comment: Something like this. but c.type is returning something like "nbf", "aud", "iss", but doesn't return my claims